# creating a weight vector for groups of data

Tags: r, portfolio

The data I am using is in regards to financial data. The issue I have is that I want to assign weights to a number of firms within a given portfolio. That is if I have 3 firms (as in the example below) I want to assign equal weights to each of the 3 firms in the portfolio, 0.33% for each firm. I think it will also be interested in randomly assign weights to firms within a portfolio when the size of the portfolio increases and having to manually type the specific weights can be cumbersome.

The data looks like the following:

Which can be created using the `tidyquant` package using the following code:

```
stock_returns_monthly <- c("AAPL", "GOOG", "NFLX") %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2010-01-01",
         to = "2015-12-31") %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "monthly",
               col_rename = "Ra")

stock_returns_monthly_multi <- stock_returns_monthly %>%
  tq_repeat_df(n = 3)
```

`n = 3` sets the number of portfolios to create.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   portfolio [1]
  portfolio symbol date            Ra
      <int> <chr>  <date>       <dbl>
1         1 AAPL   2010-01-29 -0.103 
2         1 AAPL   2010-02-26  0.0654
3         1 AAPL   2010-03-31  0.148 
4         1 AAPL   2010-04-30  0.111 
5         1 AAPL   2010-05-28 -0.0161
6         1 AAPL   2010-06-30 -0.0208
```

I have two problems I am trying to acheive:

1) Set equal weights across all the firms for each portfolio, the following code works.

```
weights <- c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33,
             0.33, 0.33, 0.33,
             0.33, 0.33, 0.33)
```

However problems occur when the number of firms increase and/or the number of portfolios increase.

2) Randomly assign weights to each firm in each portfolio.

The next step is to create the following table using;

```
stocks <- c("AAPL", "GOOG", "NFLX")
weights_table <-  tibble(stocks) %>%
  tq_repeat_df(n = 3) %>%
  bind_cols(tibble(weights)) %>%
  group_by(portfolio)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   portfolio [3]
  portfolio stocks weights
      <int> <chr>    <dbl>
1         1 AAPL     0.330
2         1 GOOG     0.330
3         1 NFLX     0.330
4         2 AAPL     0.330
5         2 GOOG     0.330
6         2 NFLX     0.330
7         3 AAPL     0.330
8         3 GOOG     0.330
9         3 NFLX     0.330
```

The above results are for the equally weighted data. Again, the problem occurs when the number of firms increase and the portfolio size increases.

Heres the `dput` link [dput data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/krp90aw0qcwbvxo/stackdelete.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Ran out of space: Question continued. I am trying to do two things to the `weights` vector.

Comment: 1) Randomly assign weights for each each firm across each portfolio dependent on the number of firms and portfolios.

Comment: 2) Set equal weights across all the firms for each portfolio.

so Portfolio 1: `firm 1 = 0.33`, `firm 2 = 0.33`, `firm 3 = 0.33`

The weights for each portfolio should not be greater than 1.

Comment: Comments are transient, so don't put critical information in comments; please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51235645/edit) your question and include details in the main body of your post! I also don't understand what you're asking. Do you somehow want to determine `weights` from the source data? If so, what are the rules? If not, what's the point of providing the source data?

Comment: Edited the main question. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking `stock_returns_monthly_multi` dataset as `df`. Note that `df` seems to be already grouped on `portfolio`. Using `dplyr`: `weights` will be equally divided among number of `symbol` in each `portfolio` independently.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- stock_returns_monthly_multi

df %>% 
   distinct(portfolio, symbol) %>% 
mutate(weights = 1/n())

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   portfolio [3]
#  portfolio symbol weights
#      <int> <chr>    <dbl>
#1         1 AAPL     0.333
#2         1 GOOG     0.333
#3         1 NFLX     0.333
#4         2 AAPL     0.333
#5         2 GOOG     0.333
#6         2 NFLX     0.333
#7         3 AAPL     0.333
#8         3 GOOG     0.333
#9         3 NFLX     0.333
```

***EDIT:*** If you need to randomly assign weights adding to 1, for each portfolio independently. you can evaluate weights, *w = x/ sum(x) for each portfolio, where elements of x are i.i.d. runif[0,1]*. `prop.table` can be used to achieve this:

```
df %>% 
   distinct(portfolio, symbol) %>% 
mutate(weights = prop.table(runif(n())))

#+ + # A tibble: 9 x 3
## Groups:   portfolio [3]
#  portfolio symbol weights
#      <int> <chr>    <dbl>
#1         1 AAPL     0.548
#2         1 GOOG     0.292
#3         1 NFLX     0.160
#4         2 AAPL     0.107
#5         2 GOOG     0.140
#6         2 NFLX     0.754
#7         3 AAPL     0.195
#8         3 GOOG     0.417
#9         3 NFLX     0.387
```

*This is a quick / easy way to achieve it but has issues with **statistical accuracy***, Refer this very interesting post: [Randomly generated weights sum to one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/generate-uniformly-distributed-weights-that-sum-to-unity). We can code the accepted answer into a function (`gen_weight_vec`) and use with `mutate`. Something like:

```
gen_weight_vec <- function(n){x <- runif(n) 
                              y <- -log(x) 
                              return(y/sum(y))}

df_weight <- df %>% 
                distinct(portfolio, symbol) %>% 
             mutate(weights = gen_weight_vec(n()))
```

You can check weights sum for each `porfolio`:

```
 summarise(df_weight, sum_weights = sum(weights))

## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  portfolio sum_weights
#      <int>       <dbl>
#1         1          1 
#2         2          1
#3         3          1
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted! One final point, do you know how `mutate(weights = 1/n())` can be changed to randomly create weights?

Comment: I applied the following; `weights_table <- stock_returns_monthly_multi %>%
  distinct(portfolio, symbol) %>% 
  mutate(weights = runif(n=1, min=1e-12, max=.9999999999))` however this randomly assigns a weight for all firms in each portfolio. I am trying to randomly assign weights to all firms in portfolio 1, and then randomly assign weights to all firms in portfolio 2 etc.

Comment: If i understand you fine. For that you need to create a random weight vector  for each portfolio to add to one independently. ???

Comment: it become quite interesting problem now. I edited my answer to achieve the same. Also, added some issues with statistical accuracy as pointed out in an interesting cross validated post. I would suggest you to add this issue and arrange your post a bit concisely so that others in similar need can find  your post

Comment: Removed solution

Comment: Good question now. +1

Comment: Do add the dput link to your data as provided previously.

Comment: Added again, the code is fully reprodicible but the dput is there for a backup.